# Steam User data

Tags: steam

i have little background on HTML and JavaScript and starting understanding JSON.

I want to request a json file like code below using input the steam id. Then display it, i can handle the css of the display, i just want to know how to request and set as a data for my webpage.

Many thanks.

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198090994771",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "DOƝ JU∀Ɲ™",
                "lastlogoff": 1418296775,
                "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/donjuanz/",
                "avatar": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/0e/0e5a6a7df4729fe51f58810d78b11196a16dacaa.jpg",
                "avatarmedium": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/0e/0e5a6a7df4729fe51f58810d78b11196a16dacaa_medium.jpg",
                "avatarfull": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/0e/0e5a6a7df4729fe51f58810d78b11196a16dacaa_full.jpg",
                "personastate": 1,
                "realname": "DON JUANZ",
                "primaryclanid": "103582791436871754",
                "timecreated": 1368034529,
                "personastateflags": 0,
                "loccountrycode": "GB"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [GetPlayerSummaries](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29) method on the Steam API.

Requesting JSON from that API can be done with simple HTTP requests, but you'll need to first register an API key with Steam.

The techniques for making an HTTP request in server code will vary depending on the server languages/frameworks involved.

(Using the key and making the request in javascript code is not recommended, since that would allow others to hijack your key. The typical practice is to have code on your web server make the HTTP request to Steam's API when needed.)